# How to fixed a number and after that increase automatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

here i want to set a fix number in my application like----
  text box =   10001
after that i want to increase it automatically like '10001','10002','10003; etc.
here short_no is 1 so the text box have to show 1001 ,if the short_no will be 2 then the text box show 20001 .i am fetching the short_no from database ,but not able to increase it .

```
string sql = ("select * from add_cpy where co_name = '" + txt_cname.Text + "'");

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);

SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

DataTable dt7 = new DataTable();

if (dr.Read())//if card register
{
    txt_autoNo.Text = (dr["short_no"].ToString()) + "0001";
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: Do not concat your sql strings like that. Use SqlParamaters.

Comment: How is the column "short_no" set up in DB? You can set it to auto-increase (at least in all major RDBMS like MS SQL Server, MySQL, SQLite ... ) This will increase the number on insert.

Comment: yeah i  am fetching short_no and my short_no is 1 ,2 ,3, 4, 5  . if user short_no will be 1 then text box show 10001 and after one transaction it will increase ,when user come again  with same short_no like 1 then text box show 10002 , so my question is  i can't able to auto increase this number ?

Comment: So, If I understand correctly: First (left-most) digit(s) shall identify users and the right-most 4 digits shall identify something like a "transaction-count"? If so, you'd need to have another column and increase its value in each transaction. Then you can concat the two, formatting the transaction-count to use leading zeros to fill 4 places.

Comment: yes sir ..exactly what i want .please help me

Comment: Another thought about that: This limits transactions to 9999. Is that reasonable? You could be more flexible with a formatting that has a separator. Like for example "<userId>:<transactioncount>" That would result for user "1" with 500 transactions in "1:500".

Comment: no there is no limits ...

Comment: I thought so. Now you'll have a problem starting at transaction no 10000: "112345" - is it user "11" with 2345 transactions or user "1" with 12345 transactions?

Comment: no sir , 1 is my short_no that identifies the user and the transaction no is 0001 so i want to increase it automatically  10001 to 10002 and so on,